# Trying to make banner/image responsive

Tags: css, themes, wordpress-theming

http://www.otislandscapeassociates.com/about/

I am experimenting with a banner ( the landscape image of twigs), but i am having difficulties in making it responsive across devices, e.g desktop, tablet, mobile without the image being stretched or not fitting correctly or being cut off at either end.

Would like some advice on how to get around this, also if i need to adjust the dimensions of the actually image, is it to big? Should it be smaller? etc.

I am currently doing everything in css, so this is my preferred method of modification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
background-size: contain;
```

its the easiest way to make a background image to be responsive.
But note as the width adjusts with the screen width, it will also make the image proportionally reduce in height.

I can see you have a fixed height and already use

```
background-size: cover;
```

which is what i'll normally recommended if you want it auto fill the container irrespective of the size of the container.

You cant have both (not stretched & always fill irrespective of the size of container). Looking at the image ( the white space that blends with the page & assuming its a must use) i suggest you add this to the class so it remains responsive but always fixes the design at the bottom of the div so it can always blend into the white above. Let me know if you need any clarification or questions

```
background-position: center 100%;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I've tried numerous ways, not sure if i'm putting things in the right order, but i am working with this which controls the image: /*adjust page-post image height*/
.single .entry-header, .page .entry-header {
 height: 300px;
 background-size: cover;
 /*margin: 80px 0 0;*/
}

Comment: Try this
.single .entry-header, .page .entry-header {
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
Note that this will 
(1) Make the background FIT into the container width and be responsive but wont FILL it because of difference in aspect ratio.

Comment: Or you can try  background-size: 100%; try either this or background-size: contain; (mentioned above) and see which gives you your desired result

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply and help, much appreciated, the code you have supplied seems to have given some interesting results in other words yes it has worked - thank you. Now I'm going to playing around with what you have suggested and understand this better.